# How to integrate FCM (firebase cloud messaging) with react-native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react-native app and I am required to integrate FCM push notification service, so how can I integrate it?

Comment: Wow, this is not even close to enough information to go on. You need to be a lot more specific about what you've already tried, what is or isn't working, what your existing app structure looks like, etc. Have you even read the official documentation for FCM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this module
https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

Install

```
npm i -S react-native-fcm
```

Link the library to your iOS/Android project

```
react-native link react-native-fcm
```

Check the configuration and usage details in the README

Comment: Hi, I would like to know if there is a way to integrate FCM without using the evilly . . I am planning to use just the guide here: [link]http://invertase.io/react-native-firebase/#/modules/cloud-messaging?id=createlocalnotificationnotification-object[link] is this possible? As for now I am can get the message notification via "onMessage" event on the console log and I am do not know how to implement it on real notification.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and I find out there were 2 ways

1. **[react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm):** Simple and Easy to use.
2. **Create my own module!** why reinvent the wheel right? but [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) has 79+ open issues and hasn't been updated since past 1-month while Firebase is changing very rapidly.

So decide to create my own module and handle it my own way.If you are planning to make your own module then I have shared my code on this Git Repo: https://github.com/hiteshsahu/react-native-fcm-android.

Hope it helps.